# Modify cmdline.txt

Tags: serial-console, cmdline.txt

I have raspberry-pi cm3 image using yocto poky warrior branch. I was trying to communicate using ttyAMA0 serial port. 
I was able to do that by first manually modifying cmdline.txt from 
`console=ttyAMA0, 115200` to `console=tty1`
and then executing the command `systemctl mask serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service` then performing a reboot.

My question is, is there a way to modify cmdline.txt from the terminal? Without the need to manually edit the files.

I see the loaded cmdline arguments by going into /proc/cmdline.
Also I do not have cmdline.txt in /boot directory

Comment: You did modify cmdline.txt manually. You don't do it from the terminal? Where is your cmdline.txt located if not in `/boot/`? Does your RasPi boot then?

Comment: @Ingo Yes, My Raspi does boot. the file is located in boot partition and is not mounted.